# Optimal grayscale Image compression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, base64, compression, grayscale

I capture frames from build-in web camera using Javascript and HTML5 and intent to send them asynchronous to my server in BASE64 format.

The problem is that the total size of these frames is huge!

My thought is to turn these RGBA images from 4 channels to 1 (as I really need 8-bit grayscale frames).

The following snippet (and all the others I found) turn them grayscale, but use 4 channel again and convert them to BASE64 format using canvas method `toDataURL()`. Thus, the total size remains the same.

```
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 34, 26);

        let grayscale = []; // desired one channel 8-bit array

        for (var y = 0; y < imgData.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < imgData.width; x++) {

                var i = y * 4 * imgData.width + x * 4;

                var weighted = 
                    Math.floor( // round in order to use 8-bit integers
                        0.299 * imgData.data[i] + 
                        0.587 * imgData.data[i + 1] + 
                        0.114 * imgData.data[i+2]
                    );

                imgData.data[i] = weighted;
                imgData.data[i + 1] = weighted;
                imgData.data[i + 2] = weighted;

                grayscale.push(weighted);
            }
        }

        cxt.putImageData(
            imgData,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            imgData.width,
            imgData.height
        );

        b64 = cxt.canvas.toDataURL().split(",")[1];
```

My question is the following:

How can I send only the desired one 8-bit channel using the smallest amount of bytes?

Comment: You could try using `toDataURL('image/webp')` as that can use a palette so should get some good compression from greyscale, the default is PNG & most likely 32bit.  webp will also do Lossless and Lossy compression, for no lossless I assume you would set second param to 1..

Comment: thank you @Keith, webp format could help on the compression

Answer (score 2):

> I capture frames from build-in web camera using Javascript and HTML5 and intent to send them asynchronous to my server in BASE64 format.
>
> The problem is that the total size of these frames is huge!

Well, yeah, you're taking a raw image, and then unnecessarily adding 33% storage overhead by encoding that blob as base64.

## Drop the Base-64 Encoding

You can use the Fetch API to POST a blob directly to your server, in binary.  No text compatibility nonsense and overhead needed.

```
fetch('/image-storage', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: blob
});
```

You get your blob from calling `.toBlob()` on the canvas.

## Don't Use a Raw Image

Your source is a webcam... do you really need the raw pixels?  Probably not.  Use a lossy format like WebP or JPEG instead, when you call `.toBlob()` on your canvas.  Even with a high quality setting, you're going to save a lot of data.

## If you must have raw greyscale...

Calculate your greyscale pixels using whatever method you desire, and write them to a buffer.  Use that buffer in your fetch POST body.

Comment: your remarks were on point!!! Base-64 encoding and raw pixels are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

So you already have an array of bytes - I don't understand why you do the conversion back to an image and convert this image to base64. You could also simply move the bytes into an string and encode this string as base64.

```
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 34, 26);

let binary = '';

for (var y = 0; y < imgData.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < imgData.width; x++) {

        var i = y * 4 * imgData.width + x * 4;

        var weighted = 
            Math.floor( // round in order to use 8-bit integers
                0.299 * imgData.data[i] + 
                0.587 * imgData.data[i + 1] + 
                0.114 * imgData.data[i+2]
            );

        binary += String.fromCharCode(weighted);
    }
}

// do the conversion
b64 = window.btoa(binary);
```